# How can i retrieve a labels previous location when it is moved

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to implement a swing undo function that returns a label to its previous location on a jPanel when the undo Button is pressed. I added a component lister to the label but I can only get the current location and don't know how to get the previous location of the label.

```
  class ComponentEventAdapter implements ComponentListener {

    @Override
    public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
        //do nothing.
    }

    @Override
    public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {

           Point oldP;
           Point newP = e.getComponent().getLocation();

        undoManager.undoableEditHappened(new UndoableEditEvent(modelPanel, new ComponentAdditionEdit(e.getComponent(),oldP , newP)));

    }

    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        // Do nothing.

    }

    @Override
    public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {          
        undoManager.undoableEditHappened(new UndoableEditEvent(modelPanel, new ComponentAdditionEdit(e.getComponent(),e.getComponent().getLocation())));
    }

}
```

How do I pass the labels/components old location to oldP.

Comment: How is the move initially triggered (MouseListener? ActionListener?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way (I think) would be to create a new class that extends `JLabel` which is identical in every way except it has an `oldP` variable. Like:

```
class superNeatJLabel extends JLabel {

    public Point oldP;

    public superNeatJLabel() {
        super();
        oldP = this.getLocation()
    }
}
```

Then just update or check `oldP` as needed. Alternatively, you could make `oldP` private and add getters and setters, but that's up to you. It's also probable this won't be exactly your constructor, considering that often times swing components are instantiated before they have bounds and such, but hopefully this is enough to get the idea across.

Futher, if you're a pro at polymorphism, you can extend `Component` instead and use this type for all your `Components` That might get tricky though, seeing as you can't instantiate a `Component`, but it's certainly possible.

Comment: Thanks, I was already using subclasses of JLabel, I added the two fields oldP and newP and created a method that passed the alue of newP to oldP before updating newP to the labels current position.